# Not showing all the selected field using SELECT query - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select some fields from the table with customized values, When I run the select query its showing first two selected columns irrespective of the order in select query (like country,name,slug,area_slug or country,slug,area_slug,name).

please find the table schema and the query below.

```
TABLE:
    CREATE TABLE `destination` (
      `code` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
      `country` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
      `region` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `parent` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
      `latitude` double(30,15) NOT NULL,
      `longitude` double(30,15) NOT NULL,
      `updated` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00T00:00:00.000000Z'
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

QUERY:

SELECT 'ae' as country,
       name,
       replace(lcase(name), ' ', '-') as slug,
       CONCAT(replace(lcase(name), ' ', '-'),'-united-arab-emirates') as area_slug  
FROM `destination` 
WHERE code IN ("18ed5","18ed6","18ed7","18ed8","18ed9","18eda","18edb")
```

Comment: You do not have a column named `ae`

Comment: I am putting the value as 'ae' in country column.

Comment: @MohammedAbrarAhmed did you try to change `as country` to something like `as country_2` ... because you already have a column named `country` in the table and ... it can be confusing ;)

Comment: @MohammedAbrarAhmed Please can you show what you get that is not correct?

Comment: @Randall , no effects even I change the column name.

Comment: Dont see what is the problem.   Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/0mVdE

Comment: Thanks for sharing the status report. Was there a *question*?

Comment: @spencer7593, I just see two columns in the query result even if I select 4 in the query.

Comment: You have something else wrong, a simple demo show is working ok. http://rextester.com/QSE53544

Comment: @MohammedAbrarAhmed: and what result do you get when you execute the SQL statement from the mysql command line client? (i.e. executing from a `mysql>` prompt). I don't think the issue is with the SQL statement, or with the resultset returned by the MySQL Server. I suspect the issue is with whatever MySQL client you are using... and the status report leaves us just guessing at what that might be... phpMyAdmin? MYSQL Workbench? TOAD for MySQL? SQLyog? HeidiSQL? Henplus? You might notice (from the comments) some confusion about the status report (i hesitate to call it a *question*)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/caaa6/1/0 seems to provide the 4 columns.  can't recreate the error.  Provide a MCVE so we can help debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

According to the error message in the screenshot provided you **do not have a unique column** in the query, and that is true. There does not even seem to be one in the table. I suggest you add an auto incrementing ID into your table, then include that column in your query.

for example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `destination`;

CREATE TABLE `destination` (

  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment primary key,

      `code` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
      `country` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
      `region` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `parent` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
      `latitude` double(30,15) NOT NULL,
      `longitude` double(30,15) NOT NULL,
      `updated` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00T00:00:00.000000Z'
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

INSERT INTO     `destination` (code,country,region,name,parent,latitude,longitude,updated)
VALUES ('18ed5','1','1','1','1','1',1,2);

SELECT   ID
       , 'ae'                                                            AS country 
       , name 
       , REPLACE(Lcase(name), ' ', '-')                                  AS slug 
       , Concat(REPLACE(Lcase(name), ' ', '-'), '-united-arab-emirates') AS area_slug 
FROM   `destination` 
WHERE  code IN ( '18ed5', '18ed6', '18ed7', '18ed8','18ed9', '18eda', '18edb' )
```

**result**

```
| ID | country | name | slug |       area_slug        |
|----|---------|------|------|------------------------|
|  1 | ae      |    1 |    1 | 1-united-arab-emirates |
```

see: http://rextester.com/LER16583

Comment: I think there is something wrong with table , when I am trying to access the destination table it says https://imgur.com/a/MfVwY

Comment: Maybe, can't help you with that. Is that a PHPMYADMIN screen?

Comment: I just drop the table and created again,working fine now.